# Error in pychram while importing a file in other file

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, python-import

Please help me out....

I have 2 files namely 1.py and 2.py ,

I want to import 1.py in 2.py , when I use import 1.py in 2.py ;

It shows me error as no modules found even though both the files are in same folder/directory.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: please share the trace and console output

Comment: It'd be better if you show the code or show us how you are importing it.

Answer (score -2):

you shouldn't write
`import 1.py`
just
`import 1`
or
`from 1 import something`

I recommend [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) reading. It will help you understand how imports work in python.